# I am facing License Limit Exceeded Exception when trying to insert a new user through apex controller class

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have created a visualforce page for creating new user and through the controller class I am trying to insert the newly created user.

I am working on a developer org and has three licenses available for - Salesforce Platform - User License.
I have created 4 users with this license in my org and only one of them is active.

Still I am facing the License Limit Exceeded Exception while I am trying to insert a new user with this license.

Can anyone please suggest a solution for this issue?

The code I am using is -

```
    newUser = new User();

    newUser.email = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('email');
    String[] name = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('name').split(' ',2);
    newUser.firstName = name[0];
    newUser.lastName = name[1];
    newUser.userName = newUser.email;

    UserRole usrRole = [select id, name from UserRole where name = 'Customer'];
    Profile prof = [select id, name from Profile where name = 'Customer Portal'];

    newUser.UserRoleId = usrRole.id;
    newUser.ProfileId = prof.id;
    newUser.isActive = true;
    try
    {            
        insert newUser;
        alertMsg = 'Successfully Created New User';                
    }
    catch(System.DMLException e)
    {                 
        alertMsg = e.getMessage();         
    }
```

The screen shot of my company information is -

[image: Company Information for User Licenses]

Comment: Can you go to Setup -> Company Profile -> Company Information and add the User Licenses information to your question?

Comment: I have added the company information and my code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
In the developer console, run this anonymous apex code snippet to get a count of active and inactive users:
    system.debug([select isactive, count(Id) from User group by isactive]);

The outcome of the above SQL should be 3 inactive users and 1 active (as per your problem statement).

Option 2:
Make sure your controller class is not bulk inserting users beyond the # of open licenses.

Option 3:
Make sure your code is not trying to create user(s) using a profile that is tied to a license type that is all used up.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear Rajesh, actually my org has 6 active users it was only about the user license - Salesforce Platform that I said has 3 inactive and 1 active user, that makes it to use 1 of the 3 available "Salesforce Platform" Licenses. I am trying to insert only one new user still facing the problem.

Comment: Can you share your controller code and also a screenshot of your developer org's "company information" showing the license details?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the profile, you also need to set the UserType (aka license type), otherwise it defaults to the Salesforce license, for which you have no spares, you need to add
something like `newUser.userType = 'Platform'` (you'll need to use describeSObject or a schema viewer tool to find the exact picklist value to use)

Comment: I tried assigning value to newUser.userType but it gives me error that this field is not writable and anyhow when we assign a profile with a user it should take the associated license of that profile as it's  userType.

Comment: when you create new user via the UI you have to pick the user type.

Comment: Yes that's true but through apex class can't set userType that field is not writable.